# Problem in solving non linear set of equation?

Tags: equation-solving, webmathematica, nonlinear

I am trying to solve a set of non linear equation but using the function nsolve but mathematica is not giving me proper answer. The code is given below.

```
h = 0.8;
\[Epsilon]r = 2.94;
ae = 5;
```

The Equations are given below.

Equation Number 1....

```
1/we = (120*\[Pi])/(ae (w/h + 1.393 + 0.667*Log[w/h + 1.44]));
```

Equation Number 2....

```
1/we = (4.38/
ae)*(E^((-0.627*\[Epsilon]r)/(((\[Epsilon]r + 1)/
  2) + (\[Epsilon]r - 1)/2 + 1/Sqrt[(1 + (12*h)/w)])));
```

Nsolve for solving both equations for "we" and "w" simultaneously.

```
NSolve[{1/we == (120*\[Pi])/(
ae (w/h + 1.393 + 0.667*Log[w/h + 1.44])), 
1/we == 4.38/
ae*(E^((-0.627*\[Epsilon]r)/(((\[Epsilon]r + 1)/
   2) + (\[Epsilon]r - 1)/2 + 1/Sqrt[(1 + (12*h)/w)])))}, {we, 
w}, Reals]
```

I am not getting any solution for the above equations using NSOLve.

Comment: `NSolve` deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations. In your case you might have more luck using e.g. `FindRoot` with an adequate estimate of the solution values.

Comment: Using `{{w, 100}, {we, 2}}` for the starting values should do it with `FindRoot` as recommended by MarcoB.

Comment: @JimBaldwin ,  I used the `Find Root` Method with the code given below .`FindRoot[{1/we == (120*\[Pi])/(
   ae (w/h + 1.393 + 0.667*Log[w/h + 1.44])), 
  1/we == (4.38/
     ae)*(E^((-0.627*\[Epsilon]r)/(((\[Epsilon]r + 1)/
       2) + (\[Epsilon]r - 1)/2 + 1/Sqrt[(1 + (12*h)/w)])))}, {{w, 
   100}, {we, 2}}]`        But that gives me some dimension related error .

Answer (score 2):

Using the starting value `{w,100}` and setting both sides equal (we can ignore the reciprocal `1/we`) and then solve for `w` first. Apologies to Jim and MarcoB, this is a rip answer to clean things up.

```
h = 0.8;
\[Epsilon]r = 2.94;
ae = 5;

eqn = (120*\[Pi])/(ae (w/h + 1.393 + 0.667*Log[w/h + 1.44])) == 
(4.38/ae)*(E^((-0.627*\[Epsilon]r)/(((\[Epsilon]r + 1)/
        2) + (\[Epsilon]r - 1)/2 + 1/Sqrt[(1 + (12*h)/w)])));

FindRoot[eqn, {w, 100}] (* Gives  w -> 106.761 *)
1/(eqn[[1]] /. w -> 106.761) (* Implies we is 1.83182 *)
```

Comment: @Histograms...Thanks for your answer..This was really helpful.

Comment: No need to apologize. Thank you for writing this up!